# Programmatically add constraints to View in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm creating TextViews programmatically and adding them to my constraint layout. They are by default placed in the top left corner. I want them to go below each other, the first one being below an EditText.

This is my code:

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.cLayout);
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // Width of TextView
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
set.clone(layout);
set.connect(tv.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 8);
set.connect(tv.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, editText.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
tv.setId(View.generateViewId());
set.applyTo(layout);
layout.addView(tv,0);
```

As you see, I've already set a constraint from TOP of View to BOTTOM of editText. Still, it shows in the top left corner. Why is that?

Comment: As per the guideline always avoid programmatically adding views.

Comment: @SumitShukla But what if I'm fetching text headlines from a website and the textviews can't already be there, I have to create them? If I have 3 headlines, I have to add three textviews. If I have one, only add one.

Comment: Just asking why do you want to do that in code when it can be done easily in layout xml file or by using the layout editor. It would be better if you don't bloat your classes with UI related data as much

Comment: @JouanH.Sulaiman You don't need to create the Textview at run-time in this case. Just keep the Textview where you want it and set its text to empty string. That is it and when the data comes just set its text again to what you fetched.

Comment: First off thank you Shukla and Jamil for answering me. However I don't know how many Textviews I want before fetching the data, so what to do in this case?

Comment: @JouanH.Sulaiman In which manner are you displaying the TextViews ? A list right ? What you need is to read about ListViews , GridViews , RecyclerView and Adpater Views. These views are also called view groups. View group mean those views which can contain other views inside them and the arrange them in a certain manner. A ListView will arrange all its containing views in a list manner etc. These views get there data from an Adapter. Adapter will contain an Array of data which in your case are the fetched text. Read here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code order isn't proper, the following code should work.

```
ConstraintLayout layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.cLayout);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Something");
tv.setId(View.generateViewId());
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // Width of TextView
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
layout.addView(tv,0);

ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.clone(layout);
set.connect(tv.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 8);
set.connect(tv.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, editText.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 8);
set.applyTo(layout);
```

P.S - I agree with Syed Ahmed Jamil that you should preferably use a `RecyclerView` or `ListView`, but it doesn't hurt to know how to set `ConstraintLayout` constraints properly.

Comment: Thank you so much. What if I'm adding many textviews, and I want each successive one to be below the one before it? Is there a way around that?

Comment: You could hold the generated ID for the text view, and use that ID instead of `editText.getId()`. Rather than doing something like that, You should use a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView`, they scale much better and are more easier to maintain and design (to suit your requirements).